# Split string by an index value (not middle of the word)

Tags: java

So here is an example

String str = 'Java is a high-level programming language originally developed by Sun Microsystems and released in 1995'

Trying to come up with method that will split the string based on the index value defined but if that index is in the middle of the word it will split it after the word.

So if say the index is 31 , that would actually split the sentence
like this (***each line is 31 characters long***)

```
Java is a high-level programmin
g language originally developed 
by Sun Microsystems and release
d in 1995
```

Notice how the word "*programming*" and "*released*" were split. If the character at index is not a space, I would like to advance the to the next space and then split the string. For example:

```
Java is a high-level programming
language originally developed by
Sun Microsystems and released in
1995
```

In the above illustration, no word was split (each line is ***at least*** 31 characters long).

Comment: Maybe start at the chosen index then `find` the next whitespace?  Or the next and previous whitespaces and choose the closest one?

Comment: Use substring on the string from 0 to the index then split this by spaces, and get the length of the array (-1). This is the index of your word.

Comment: This is a confusing requirement. I guess you want to start at the index of `word` (i.e. "split) and end after the next white space from `index`.  But, I can also see you probably mean 31 characters after `word`? Which one is it?

Comment: What is the output of your example, "split" or "split based on the index defined,"? Also, what happens if "index" is less than the index of the word?

Comment: @hfontanez , I have updated my question to make it easier

Comment: That didn't help. I will edit your question and afterwards, please fill in the missing information.

Comment: I believe thats all the information needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way. No explicit loops involved.

- find midpoint of string.
- find first space after mid point.
- find first space before mid point.
- select split position based on distance from midpoint.

```
int mid = str.length()/2;
int indexBeyondMid = str.indexOf(' ',mid);
int indexBeforeMid = str.substring(0,mid).lastIndexOf(' ');
int splitPoint = mid - indexBeforeMid < indexBeyondMid - mid 
         ? indexBeforeMid 
         : indexBeyondMid;
String firstHalf = str.substring(0,splitPoint);
String secondHalf = str.substring(splitPoint+1); // ignores leading space.
System.out.println(firstHalf);
System.out.println(secondHalf);
```

The above will split as evenly as possible. If you want to just split on the first space after the mid point, then just split on `indexBeyondMid` and forget the rest.

If you want to split a line as optimally as possible to a specified linewidth, you can do it like this.

```
int lineWidth = 19;
while (!str.isBlank()) {
    lineWidth = lineWidth > str.length() ? str.length() : lineWidth;
    int indexBeyondMid = str.indexOf(' ',lineWidth);
    int indexBeforeMid = str.substring(0,lineWidth).lastIndexOf(' ');
    int splitPoint = lineWidth - indexBeforeMid < indexBeyondMid - lineWidth 
             ? indexBeforeMid 
             : indexBeyondMid;
    if (splitPoint < 0) {
        System.out.println(str);
        break;
    }
    System.out.println(str.substring(0, splitPoint));
    str = str.substring(splitPoint+1);
}
```

prints

```
Hey I am string that
will be split but
remember i will not
be cut in the middle
of the word
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple solution:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main
{

  public static String[] splitBy(String text, int index)
  {
    int charIn = 0;
    String[] defaultArray = new String[2];

    for(charIn = index; charIn < text.length(); charIn++)
    {
      if(text.charAt(charIn) == ' ')
      {
        defaultArray[0] = text.substring(0, charIn);
        defaultArray[1] = text.substring(charIn, text.length() - 1);

        return defaultArray;
      }
    }

    return defaultArray;
  }
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    String text = "This is a nice text"; // Your text
    int index = 10; // Index to split

    System.out.println(splitBy(text, index)[0]); // Print first part of the splitted
    System.out.println(splitBy(text, index)[1]); // Print part 2
  }
}
```